# Ant Script return code problem while using with shell script?

Tags: unix, shell, ant, return-code

Hi i am currently working with mqfte. I use a shell script to invoke an ant script. In turn the ant invokes a transfer. In case of the transfer failure i need a return code 1 and 0 in case of success. For this i am using $? in my shell script after the ant invoking step. But in both cases i get a return code 1. what could be the problem with this? the operating system used is unix.

Comment: edit your question to include minimal ant script AND the offending shell script. Otherwise it is too difficult to guess what is going on. OR use `set -vx` to see the shell debug trace. you may see something happening that you don't expect. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please edit your question to include minimal ant script AND the offending shell script. Otherwise it is too difficult to guess what is going on.

OR use `set -vx` to see the shell debug trace. you may see something happening that you don't expect.